# Does it matter if we specify 'super' in an overridable method

Tags: java, android

Does it matter if we do specify the keyword "super" when overriding methods?

If yes, under what condition it does matter?

```
1.   
@Override
public void foo() {
super.foo();
}

2. 
@Override
public void foo() {
}
```

Comment: `super.foo()` calls the `foo` method of the superclass.  If that's what you want to do, then write it.  If it isn't what you want to do, then don't.  This isn't like a constructor where you either have to put in `super(...)` or the language will stick one in for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It matters if the `super` has any work to do in their implementation of the method.

And usually, the `super` does have some work to do, otherwise the method would be abstract instead of overridable.

If you have written the `super`, then you know whether `super` should be invoked.  If someone else has written the `super`, you need to look at their documentation.

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, then by default, IntelliJ IDEA will issue a warning if you omit calling super.  Under Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java -> Inheritance issues you will find a "Method does not call super method" inspection which controls this warning.  If you want this warning to be issued on specific methods instead of all methods, then you can make use of the "Only report when supper method is annotated by:" option.  I have created the following annotation for this:

```
package javax.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

/**
 * Overriding-Methods-Must-Invoke-Super annotation.
 * See JSR 305: Annotations for Software Defect Detection
 *              (https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305)
 */
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.CLASS )
@Target( ElementType.METHOD )
public @interface OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper
{
}
```

This way, when I really want all descendants to invoke super, I annotate the super with `@OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper`.

Comment: The question is tagged Android, so there's a ready-made [annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/CallSuper.html) for this.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you want to happen. If the parent class (super) has functionality that you still want to be executed, then calling `super.foo()` is needed. That would be a method that might need the parent class to perform its function, and then the child class adds some more logic after the parent did its thing.

Otherwise, if you want to completely replace what the parent class is doing, you do not want to call `super.foo()`. This will make sure that whatever the parent class would have done by calling the function DOES NOT get executed. Here's an example:

```
public class Parent {
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm a Parent!");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void printSomething() {
        super.printSomething();
        System.out.println("I'm a Child!");
    }
}
```

Calling Child printSomething would result in this:

```
I'm a Parent!
I'm a Child!
```

If you did not call super.printSomething(), you would see this:

```
I'm a Child!
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the method.

If you take a framework it often does "things" in the parent method too. If you know the parent method does nothing then it doesn't matter, however for future compatibility it's a good idea to always add the call to super.

The only exception when you really don't want to have what the parent method does. In that case you have no other choice.

In fact you often end up overriding methods for that reason if you use frameworks like Android or Spring.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it matter if we do specify the keyword "super" when overriding
>   methods?

Invoking `super.methodName()` has a meaning : it invokes the method implemented in the parent class of the current instance.
So, yes it matters.

When we override a method from a parent class, we want to define a specific behavior for this subclass. This specific behavior has two flavors :

- most of time, the subclass needs also to inherit from the parent behavior (addition of parent behavior and current class behavior) : in the overrided method, we call so `super.methodName()` and we do the specific behavior.
- but in some specific cases, the subclass needs to define a specific behavior without inheriting from the behavior of the parent class : in the overrided method, we don't call `super.methodName()` and we do only the specific behavior.